# App or www folder to develop in ionic?

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, gruntjs

I think when we are programming in ionic we have do it into www folder.
But when I write into npm:

`grunt serve --lab`

grunt delete everything into www folder and make the files again. So..

**Where I have change the code?**  I bought an app. The folder that have the app are:

- .sass-cache
- .temp
- app
- hook
- misc
- node_modules
- platforms
- plugins
- resources
- test
- typing
- www

Nowadays I'm changing into app folder but if I run the server with:

```
ionic serve start
```

the serve not taking effect when I change code into app folder.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Which build of ionic are you running? With the new release candidate the structure changed and it's recommended to place things in src. The old way was placing things in app.

Comment: I dont know  how to know that